# How a session leader can take the control of tty in Linux?

Tags: linux

I was trying to daemon a process, and have found that we should fork() it twice. The reason is that if the process is a session-leader then it can take a control of tty. I was wondering, what is the rationale behind this theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first fork is to run the daemon in a separate session. What you are expected to do for daemonizing is (pseudo-code):

```
fork()
if (parent) {
    return
else if (child) {
    setsid();
    closefds();
    fork();
    if (child) {
        childwork();
    } else {
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

The [`setsid`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid) call puts the daemon in it's own session and disassociates it from the tty of the parent process. If you don't do the `setsid` call, then you don't get the new session, and the daemon could be interfered with by the process group that it still belongs to - i.e. it could be interfered by a `HUP` sent to the entire process group.

The second `fork()` call causes the process to no longer be the session leader. This means that process will not be able to acquire a controlling terminal if it opens an unused terminal device (either by accident, or intentionally) because it's not the session leader. If it was still the session leader, then you would have to make sure that all open calls that open terminal devices would have to be invoked with `O_NOCTTY` to be on the safe side.